# OptionMenu doesnt show anything

Tags: android, optionmenu

I have an `OptionMenu` inside my `activity` but when I choose an option it shows nothing. I've found some tutorials but they show what I already do. What is wrong?
Thank you for the replies.

This is the code at the moment:

```
public class Listino extends TabActivity
{
    final Context context = this;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    deleteFile("Ordinazioni.txt");
    setContentView(R.layout.show_listino);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

    //Primi
    Intent intentPrimi = new Intent().setClass(this, Primi.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecPrimi = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Primi")
            .setIndicator("Primi")
            .setContent(intentPrimi);

    //Secondi

    Intent intentSecondi = new Intent().setClass(this, Secondi.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecSecondi = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Secondi")
            .setIndicator("Secondi")
            .setContent(intentSecondi);

    // Dolci

    Intent intentDolci = new Intent().setClass(this, Dolci.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecDolci = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Dolci")
            .setIndicator("Dolci")
            .setContent(intentDolci);

    // Pizze

    Intent intentPizze = new Intent().setClass(this, Pizze.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecPizze = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Pizze")
            .setIndicator("Pizze")
            .setContent(intentPizze);

    // Bevande

    Intent intentBevande = new Intent().setClass(this, Bevande.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecBevande = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Bevande")
            .setIndicator("Bevande")
            .setContent(intentBevande);

    // Contorni

            Intent intentContorni = new Intent().setClass(this, Bevande.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecContorni = tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Contorni")
                    .setIndicator("Contorni")
                    .setContent(intentContorni);

    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecPrimi);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecSecondi);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecPizze);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecDolci);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBevande);



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
         MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
         menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.opzioni_menu, menu);  
        return true;
}

public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    Toast.makeText(context, item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.fineordinazione:
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AggiungiProdotto.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;

        case R.id.modificaordinazione:
            break;

    }
    return false;

}
```

}

Aaaw.

Comment: Naming variables in your native language (!= en) makes me giggle every time.

Comment: Like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-s8MlzzN9U ? :)

Comment: you forgot to @Override the `OnOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: I don't have to. Eclipse marks it as error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo.

Not

```
public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

but

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

The initial letter of the method name is a lower case.

Comment: "Sometimes I feel like throwing my hands up in the air. I know I can count on you." -cit.
Thank you, 2 hours of debugging now has sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to inflate menus through getMenuInflater(), not layouts.

Change:

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.opzioni_menu, menu);
```

To this:

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.opzioni_menu, menu);  //use menu, not layout
```

You should use `R.menu.bla_bla_bla` instead of `R.layout.bla_bla_bla`.

For more info, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Comment: I don't have any menu.opzioni_menu

Comment: then create one, otherwise you cannot inject menus to your activity.

Comment: Changed, but doesn't appear nothing as before. I click on my option and it doesnt change ativity. I see the app doesnt enter in the switch.

Comment: clean + refresh your project and then build again

Comment: Still nothing. I'm frustrated :S

Comment: Instead of altering your question totally, you should post a new question so we know what new problems are. Now my answer doesn't really relate to what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

create opzioni_menu.xml in res/menu/ (if you don't have menu folder, create one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/fineordinazione" android:title="fineordinazione"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/modificaordinazione" android:title="modificaordinazione"/>
</menu>
```

then change

```
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.opzioni_menu, menu);
```

to

```
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.opzioni_menu, menu);
```

Good luck hope this help !!

*edit*

```
public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

to

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

On <<<< o in lower case !! please

Comment: I've done like this but when I press the button nothing appears, it doesnt enter in the switch

Comment: remove         Toast.makeText(context, item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
or change to         Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(item.getItemId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); if you really want to see Id

Comment: The problem is the app doesnt reach that point, seems it doesnt enter in OnOptionsItemSelected

Comment: just try , may be it's stuck in Toast line

Comment: Nothing, I can't find the problem :(

Comment: I
CANT
BELIEVE. I LOVE YOU AND THE naga, THANK YOU.